# insert markup into h:outputText to enhance some words jsf

Tags: css, jsf-2

I would like to insert a `<span>`  into the value of this outputText :

```
<h:outputText id="jesuis1" value="la quantité nécéssaire : #{editCommandController.myCom.nbreExemplaire*editCommandController.myCom.nbrePage}" />
```

my goal is to enhance  this   `{editCommandController.myCom.nbreExemplaire*editCommandController.myCom.nbrePage}`  by css  but it generated an error

do you have any idea

Answer (score 0):

You need the `escape` attribute!

`<h:outputText escape="false" value="#any text including el that
evaluates to html tags"/>`

or you could use

> ```
> <h:outputFormat escape="true" value="text with {0} tags>
>     <f:param value="#{bean.htmlExpression}" />
> </h:outputFormat>
> ```